# find element with differnt ID and different XPATh on each session

Tags: selenium, xpath

```html
<section class="row line-details-main-section" ng-if="$lineDetails.userFactory.accountData">
<div class="constrain-width-1024">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 no-gutter-md no-gutter-lg">
<line-details-multiline form-content="$lineDetails.content" current-line="$lineDetails.currentLine">
<!---->
<div ng-if="$lineDetails.currentLine && $lineDetails.currentLine.details.ctn">
<line-details-plan form-content="$lineDetails.content" current-line="$lineDetails.currentLine">
<line-details-features form-content="$lineDetails.content" current-line="$lineDetails.currentLine">
<line-details-device form-content="$lineDetails.content" current-line="$lineDetails.currentLine">
<line-details-rewards form-content="$lineDetails.content" current-line="$lineDetails.currentLine">
<myc-panel class="line-details-rewards" panel-title="rewardsCtrl.formContent.linedetailsCricketRewardsTitle" collapsible="true" collapsed="rewardsCtrl.planCollapse">
<div class="panel panel-myc col-xs-12 no-gutter" ng-class="{'no-margin-bottom': $panel.last }">
<!---->
<!---->
<div class="clearfix panel-heading has-focus collapsible bg-darkgrey" ng-if="$panel.collapsible" ng-class="{'has-sub-heading': $panel.subHeading}" role="button" aria-controls="grjtg" ng-click="$panel.collapsed = !$panel.collapsed" tabindex="0">
<!---->
<!---->
<!---->
<!---->
<div id="grjtg" class="clearfix panel-body in collapse" ng-if="$panel.isBody" uib-collapse="$panel.collapsible && $panel.collapsed" ng-transclude="body" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" style="height: auto;">
</div>
</myc-panel>
</line-details-rewards>
</div>
<!---->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<!---->
</line-details>
</div>
```

I have an element which changes xpath every time but the problem is that it changes the ID.
e.g

```
//*[@id='elrgv']/myc-panel-body/div[1]/div/div
//*[@id='cdtxe']/myc-panel-body/div[1]/div/div
//*[@id='lhyxe']/myc-panel-body/div[1]/div/div
```

These are the 3 different xpaths on 3 clicks.I know how to handle if the ID is fixed but here the ID is changing.Please chelp

Comment: Can you please help us by posting the HTML dom to help you?

Comment: That simply means you can't use the id as a selector and will need to use a css selector or a more concrete xpath

Comment: the rest of the xpath is always same..how to use regular expression for the id

Comment: *the rest of the xpath is always same*... How do you know this? There might be dozens of possible XPath expressions... Just **share the HTML source sample for the same**

Comment: I am saying that the part after the id -- "myc-panel-body/div[1]/div/div" is constant in this case

Comment: <button type="submit" ng-click="rewardsCtrl.goToRewardsPage('Join Cricket Rewards')" ng-disabled="!rewardsCtrl.rewards.enrollmentUrl" class="btn btn-primary" ng-bind="::rewardsCtrl.formContent.joinRewardsBtn" data-woopra="bc0ec701a0088ec9d85db0153eb1baf52f6c914f37c427fd5c54704b">Join Now</button>

Comment: <button type="submit" ng-click="rewardsCtrl.goToRewardsPage('Join Cricket Rewards')" ng-disabled="!rewardsCtrl.rewards.enrollmentUrl" class="btn btn-primary" ng-bind="::rewardsCtrl.formContent.joinRewardsBtn" data-woopra="bc0ec701a0088ec9d85db0153eb1baf52f6c914f37c427fd5c54704b">Join Now</button>

Comment: div id="grjtg" ng-if="$panel.isBody" class="clearfix panel-body in collapse" uib-collapse="$panel.collapsible &amp;&amp; $panel.collapsed" ng-transclude="body" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" style="height: auto;"><myc-panel-body>
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-xs-12 no-gutter-md no-gutter-lg line-rewards-panel">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 no-gutter-right-md no-gutter-right-lg rewards-icon">

Comment: try `//div[contains(@class, "rewards-icon")]`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the HTML, and do not use comments for this.

Comment: done @JoshuaDrake

Answer (score 0):

Here if you observe your id is dynamic but the path to your element is static (means your element is in fix order tags e.g. `myc-panel-body/div[1]/div/div`) So you can directly able to locate the element as below :

```
//div/myc-panel-body/div[1]/div/div
```

OR 
for more reliability you can locate parent element with some other attribute e.g.

```
//div[@class='clearfix panel-body in collapse']/myc-panel-body/div[1]/div/div
```